# Ideal Number of Task Slots

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have developed a Flink application on v1.13.0 and deployed it on Kubernetes that runs a Task Manager instance on a Kubernetes pod. I am not sure how to determine the ideal number of task slots on each Task Manager instance. Should we configure/choose one task slot on each task manager/pod or two slots per Task Manager/pod or more. We currently configured two task slots per Task Manager instance and wondering if that is the right choice/setting. What are the pros and cons of running one task slot vs running two or more slots on a Task Manager/pod.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, for containerized deployments (like yours), one slot per TM is a good default starting point. This tends to keep the configuration as straightforward as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your expected workload, input, state size.

---

Is it a batch or a stream?

Batch: is the worload fast enough?

Stream: is the worload backpressuring?

For these throughput limitations, you might want to increase the number of TMs

---

State size: how are you processing your data? Does it require a lot of state?

For example, this query:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  count(*)
FROM user_logins
```

will need a state proportional with the number of users.

You can tune the memory of TM in the options.

Here is a useful link: https://www.ververica.com/blog/how-to-size-your-apache-flink-cluster-general-guidelines

---

Concurrent jobs: is this machine under-used, and do you need to keep a pool of unused TS ready to execute a job?

A TM's memory will be sliced between the TS (be sure it fits your state size), but the CPU will be shared  when idle.

---

Other than that if it's going fine on one TM on one pod then you have nothing to do.